# Why does Ubuntu Software Center need a separate login?

Tags: ubuntu-one, software-center

So there is this Ubuntu One feature which promises to be the one central place / account where I keep stuff and so on.

So why, if that is the case, do I need to register again for the Ubuntu Software Center? I honestly can't understand it is necessary to have two separate accounts for two features of the same operating system.

Or can I use my Ubuntu One account to login to Software Center somehow?

Please explain, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. USC doesn't require any extra login to function properly. You will need to authorize any changes to the system with your normal password
2. If you want to receive recommendations, you can connect USC to your Launchpad account, which is the same as your Ubuntu One account. This is purely optional. It is required because your local login information isn't shared with the Ubuntu servers at all. The only thing they know about you is your IP and optionally your Launchpad login. This is a little similar to how using Android doesn't require a Google account, but the Play Store does.
3. Connecting USC to Launchpad means that you can sync the installed software on different computers. That's quite useful in some situations.

Comment: I know USC does function without logging in. Still the USC 'register' window is confusing to me - if I understand you correctly, it is indeed possible to log in to USC with UO credentials? Then why does the window ask for new credentials?

Comment: Yes, it's confusing. Just click "I already have an account" and use your Ubuntu One / Launchpad credentials.

Comment: Wow - I never even saw that option until you pointed out it existed. I skipped looking at it because it is placed as a "forgot your password?" link...